# How to add SharePoint discussion boards Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have added new fields namely `details` in discussion content type and `details 2` in message content type. In SharePoint Workflow I'm using send mail action in which trying to get all the fields data in both content type and sending an email.

How to display all the data of both content type in SharePoint designer.